# CRM 2011 Get attributes from an entity using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, entities

I am trying to fill a read-only field automatically using a Java Script Web Resource. Now the field is dependant on a lookup containing a custom entity and a free text field of 4 characters (First part of a Postcode for Example: NW10)

I have written some JavaScript to get the values and create the new value to set in the read-only field. However when I run it the string displayed shows "[object-Object]-NW10".

I Guess what I'm asking is how do I access the attributes of the type object I passed into my function? My JavaScript is below:

```
function TypeAffectedOrRegionAffected_OnChanged(ExecutionContext, Type, Region, Weighting) {

var type = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get(Type).getValue();
var region = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get(Region).getValue();

// if we have values for both fields
if (type != null && region != null) {

    // create the weighting variable
    var weighting = type.substring(4) + "-" + region;

    // recreate the Weighting Value
    Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get(Weighting).setValue(weighting);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Type` is a lookup, so you need to access its `name` property

```js
var weighting = type[0].name.substring(4) + "-" + region;
```